# Error when checking for custom claims property on rules auth token

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I receive an error in the emulator when I try to check for a custom claim field that does not exist on the `request.auth.token` object when checking `storage.rules`.  The request fails which is correct if the property is missing but I am concerned about the error.

```js
function isPlatformVerified() {
  return request.auth.token.platformVerified == 'ok';
}
```

and this is the error shown in the emulator:

> com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.common.EvaluationException: Error: /Users/marcel/git/dev/storage.rules line [68], column [14]. Property platformVerified is undefined on object.

I wish to check if the custom claims has this property and if it has that it contains the correct value.  How do I do this without getting an error (or can I ignore this??)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the custom claim hasn't propagated to the client and rules yet.

Custom claims are part of the token that the client sends with its requests, and that token is only auto-refreshed once per hour. So it may take up to an hour before a new claim shows up in the client, and thus in the security rules.

You can force a refresh of the ID token on the client by calling [`user.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#userreload), to ensure that the new claims will be present before the auto-refresh.

Comment: Thanks Frank - but this is all locally through the emulators so surely there is no hour delay? - 
Also, this error sits within the 'rules', the issue is that I am checking for a property on the auth.token that simply might not be there for a valid reason!  Is there a way to check in rules that a property exists on this auth.token object without getting an error?

Comment: @frankvanpufflen not sure if you saw my note?  I am within the storage.rules having a helper function that needs to check if a property exists on the custom claims object (request.auth.token) -

Comment: "surely there is no hour delay" Instead of assuming that, I recommend forcing a reload of the ID token in the way I've shown. --- "Is there a way to check in rules that a property exists on this auth.token object without getting an error" Yup, that's be `in`, so **something like** `"platformVerified" in request.auth.token`.

Comment: Great thanks! The `"platformVerified" in request.auth.token` did the trick! --- I have updated the rule to be: `return "platformVerified" in request.auth.token && request.auth.token.platformVerified == 'ok';`